# pd.json_normalize used for nested JSON to Dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas

I'm trying to convert a JSON file from an api into a pandas dataframe. I have done some research which included looking at the pandas documentation and trying to find a solution that has already been provided here to no avail. pd.dataframe has worked for some of the less complex JSON files I have been converting but it would not work for a more complex nested JSON:

```
{
    "api": {
        "results": 380,
        "fixtures": [
            {
                "fixture_id": 65,
                "league_id": 2,
                "league": {
                    "name": "Premier League",
                    "country": "England",
                    "logo": "https://media.api-sports.io/football/leagues/2.png",
                    "flag": "https://media.api-sports.io/flags/gb.svg"
                },
                "event_date": "2018-08-10T19:00:00+00:00",
                "event_timestamp": 1533927600,
                "firstHalfStart": 1533927600,
                "secondHalfStart": 1533931200,
                "round": "Regular Season - 1",
                "status": "Match Finished",
                "statusShort": "FT",
                "elapsed": 90,
                "venue": "Old Trafford (Manchester)",
                "referee": null,
                "homeTeam": {
                    "team_id": 33,
                    "team_name": "Manchester United",
                    "logo": "https://media.api-sports.io/football/teams/33.png"
                },
                "awayTeam": {
                    "team_id": 46,
                    "team_name": "Leicester",
                    "logo": "https://media.api-sports.io/football/teams/46.png"
                },
                "goalsHomeTeam": 2,
                "goalsAwayTeam": 1,
                "score": {
                    "halftime": "1-0",
                    "fulltime": "2-1",
                    "extratime": null,
                    "penalty": null
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

any ideas on how the above JSON can be converted to a pandas dataframe would be appreciated please?

Comment: Have a look into [pandas.json_normalize](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html)

Comment: Hi Sushanth, I have looked at that link already and the main issue is trying to understand which parts of the JSON file are aspects are 'dict', 'record path' and 'meta'?

Comment: What is the expected output ?

Comment: Ideally I would like to have the data transferred into a postgresql database after the JSON file has been converted to a dataframe with column headings such as "fixture id" | "league_id" |  although i have just realised that this may not be possible as some of the data is nested? is there a way around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`json_normalize` is nice, but if it's deeply nested, won't flatten it out entirely. A while back I had that issue and ended up using a function to flatten it, then assemble the dataframe from that. See if this works, given the json sotred as `jsonData`

```
jsonData = {
    "api": {
        "results": 380,
        "fixtures": [
            {
                "fixture_id": 65,
                "league_id": 2,
                "league": {
                    "name": "Premier League",
                    "country": "England",
                    "logo": "https://media.api-sports.io/football/leagues/2.png",
                    "flag": "https://media.api-sports.io/flags/gb.svg"
                },
                "event_date": "2018-08-10T19:00:00+00:00",
                "event_timestamp": 1533927600,
                "firstHalfStart": 1533927600,
                "secondHalfStart": 1533931200,
                "round": "Regular Season - 1",
                "status": "Match Finished",
                "statusShort": "FT",
                "elapsed": 90,
                "venue": "Old Trafford (Manchester)",
                "referee": "null",
                "homeTeam": {
                    "team_id": 33,
                    "team_name": "Manchester United",
                    "logo": "https://media.api-sports.io/football/teams/33.png"
                },
                "awayTeam": {
                    "team_id": 46,
                    "team_name": "Leicester",
                    "logo": "https://media.api-sports.io/football/teams/46.png"
                },
                "goalsHomeTeam": 2,
                "goalsAwayTeam": 1,
                "score": {
                    "halftime": "1-0",
                    "fulltime": "2-1",
                    "extratime": "null",
                    "penalty": "null"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

**Code:**

```
import pandas as pd
import re

def flatten_json(y):
    out = {}
    def flatten(x, name=''):
        if type(x) is dict:
            for a in x:
                flatten(x[a], name + a + '.')
        elif type(x) is list:
            i = 0
            for a in x:
                flatten(a, name + str(i) + '.')
                i += 1
        else:
            out[name[:-1]] = x
    flatten(y)
    return out


flat = flatten_json(jsonData)
results = pd.DataFrame()
special_cols = []

columns_list = list(flat.keys())
for item in columns_list:
    try:
        row_idx = re.findall(r'\.(\d+)\.', item )[0]
    except:
        special_cols.append(item)
        continue
    column = re.findall(r'\.\d+\.(.*)', item )[0]

    row_idx = int(row_idx)
    value = flat[item]

    results.loc[row_idx, column] = value

for item in special_cols:
    results[item] = flat[item]
```

**Output:**

```
print (results.to_string())
   fixture_id  league_id     league.name league.country                                        league.logo                               league.flag                 event_date  event_timestamp  firstHalfStart  secondHalfStart               round          status statusShort  elapsed                      venue referee  homeTeam.team_id homeTeam.team_name                                      homeTeam.logo  awayTeam.team_id awayTeam.team_name                                      awayTeam.logo  goalsHomeTeam  goalsAwayTeam score.halftime score.fulltime score.extratime score.penalty  api.results
0        65.0        2.0  Premier League        England  https://media.api-sports.io/football/leagues/2...  https://media.api-sports.io/flags/gb.svg  2018-08-10T19:00:00+00:00     1.533928e+09    1.533928e+09     1.533931e+09  Regular Season - 1  Match Finished          FT     90.0  Old Trafford (Manchester)    null              33.0  Manchester United  https://media.api-sports.io/football/teams/33.png              46.0          Leicester  https://media.api-sports.io/football/teams/46.png            2.0            1.0            1-0            2-1            null          null          380
```

Comment: Thanks @chitown88, that solution worked! A shame that json_normalize won't flatten out entirely but this worked well.